# Why can I use a variable to stand for a function name in php?

Tags: php

I have jumped into development hell of php and a bug confused me the whole day.
I grep a sample code from a books like the following:

```
  class ThumbnailException extends Exception {
     public function __construct( $message = null, $code = 0 )
     {
         parent::__construct( $message.$code );
         error_log( 'Error in'.$this->getFile().'Line:'.
         $this->getLine().'Error:'.$this->getMessage());
     }
   }
  class ThumbnailFileException extends ThumbnailException {}
  class ThumbnailNotSupportedException extends ThumbnailException {}
  class Thumbnail {
     private $maxHeight;
     private $maxWidth;
     private $scale;
     private $inflate;
     private $types;
     private $imgLoaders;
     private $imgCreators;
     private $source;
     private $sourceWidth;
     private $sourceHeight;
     private $sourceMine;
     private $thumb;
     private $thumbWideth;
     private $thumbHeight;
     public function __construct( $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $scale = true, $inflate )
     {
         $this->maxWidth    = $maxWidth;
         $this->maxHeight   = $maxHeight;
         $this->scale       = $scale;
         $this->inflate     = $inflate;
         $this->types       = array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif' );
         $this->imgLoaders  = array(
             'image/jpeg' => 'imagecreatefromjpeg',
             'image/png' => 'imagecreatefrompng',
             'image/gif' => 'imagecreatefromgif' );
         $this->imgCreators = array(
             'image/jpeg' => 'imagejpeg',
             'image/png' => 'imagepng',
             'image/gif' => 'imagegif'
             );
     }
     public function loadFile( $image ) {
         if ( !($dims = @getimagesize($image)))
              {
                  throw new ThumbnailFileException(
                      'Couldn not find image:'.$image );
              }

              if ( in_array( $dims['mime'], $this->types ) )
              {                
                  $loader = $this->imgLoaders[$dims['mime']];
                  echo $dims['mime']. $loader.'hell';
                  $this->source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
                  $this->sourceWidth = $dims[0];
                  $this->sourceHeight = $dims[1];
                  $this->initThumb();
                  return(true);
              }else  {
                  throw new ThumbnailNotSupportedException(
                      'Image MINE types '.$dims['mime'].'not supported' );
              }
            }

$tn= new Thumbnail(200,200);
$tn->loadFile('7122559.jpeg');
header('Content-Type: '. $tn->getMine());
```

In the code above ,I set `$loader` to stand for a function name depending on the `mine` type
of `$image`. I think the code is absolutely without syntax errors. 
The problem is that when i run the code above ,it gives me `Function name must be a string` error,but I don't why? When I  change `$loader` to an exactly function name like `imagecreatefromjpeg`, it runs correctly, but I think that `$loader` is equaling  to `imagecreatefromjpeg` when `mine` of `$image` = image/jpeg. Maybe I have some rule of PHP do not know,but the code is from a books ,why it runs by errors? Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: what gives you `var_dump($loader)` ?

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you just included a [minimal  example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with which the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: if call `var_dump` the output is`string(19) "imagecreatefromjpeg"`

Comment: as it is supposed to because you declared it as a string in imgLoader. If you want to call that new name you need to call $$loader

Comment: as it is supposed to because you declared it as a string in imgLoader. If you whant to call that new name you need to call $$loader

Comment: Have you installed the GD extension? the `imagecreatefromjpeg`  function is part of this extension, so tell us what `phpinfo` or `php -i` shows you concerning image extensions being installed and enabled

Comment: @PhilipG: `$$loader`  would create a variable variable, with `imgagecreatefromjpeg`  as a name, to call `imagecreatefromjpeg` using the variable name, you simply write `$loader($arg1, $arg2);`

Comment: if i change  $loader to $$loader , the errors remains.

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem  I have install GO and I call imagecreatefromjpeg function in console is ok ,so i think imagecreatefromjpeg is working.

Comment: @timlentse: That means nothing, really... you can install GD, but that doesn't mean the PHP extension for GD (~= language bindings) have been installed. Check the phpinfo output

Comment: this is my gd information:
<pre>
GD Support enabled
GD Version 2.1.1-dev
FreeType Support enabled
FreeType Linkage with freetype
FreeType Version 2.5.2
GIF Read Support enabled
GIF Create Support enabled
JPEG Support enabled
libJPEG Version 8
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version 1.2.50
WBMP Support enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version 30411
XBM Support enabled
WebP Support enabled

Directive Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning 0 0
</pre>